# closed subspace of normed vector space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Is every finite dimensional subspace of a normed vector space closed? If yes, please prove it or else give a counter example.

Comment: By the very definition of subspace, yes.

Comment: Finite dimensional normed spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic. A finite subspace of a normed vector space $X$ is thus isomorphic to some $\ell_2^n$. As such, it is  complete; thus closed.

Comment: @DavidMitra  Thanks

Comment: Perhas chandu assumes real scalars?  Or at least a complete field for the scalars... otherwise counterexamples exist.

Comment: Do you mean topologically closed or algebraically closed (w.r.t. some operation)? I presume the former, but just want to be clear.

Comment: Topologically closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finite dimensional normed spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic. A finite subspace of a normed vector space X is thus isomorphic to some $\ell_2^n$. As such, it is complete; thus closed.